# Angular 7 with ng2-stompjs configuration

Tags: angular, angular7, stomp

I was following tutorial under the webpage: https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/ng2-stompjs/2018/11/04/ng2-stomp-with-angular7.html.

All was working great, until I got the the part where I have to externalize all the configuration for the application including websocket URL. With my insufficient knowledge of Angular, I'm finding it quite difficult to achieve this. The problem is, that in tutorial it is hardcoded:

```
export const myRxStompConfig: InjectableRxStompConfig = {
// Which server?
brokerURL: 'ws://127.0.0.1:15674/ws',
```

and I prepared this class for getting the API urls:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfig {

  private config: object = null;
  private env: object = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getConfig(key: any) {
    return this.config[key];
  }

  public getEnv(key: any) {
    return this.env[key];
  }

  getConfigs(): Promise<Object> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get('assets/config/env.json').subscribe((envResponse: any) 
=> {
    this.env = envResponse;
    let request: any = null;
    switch (envResponse.env) {
      case 'production':
      {
        request = this.http.get(
          'assets/config/api.' + this.getEnv('env') + '.json'
        );
      }
        break;

      case 'development':
      {
        request = this.http.get(
          'assets/config/api.' + this.getEnv('env') + '.json'
        );
      }
        break;

      case 'default':
      {
        console.error('Environment file is not set or invalid');
        resolve(true);
      }
        break;
    }
    if (request) {
      request.subscribe(responseData => {
        this.config = responseData;
        resolve(true);
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Env config file "env.json" is not valid');
      resolve(true);
    }
  });
});
}
}
```

I was trying with something like this:

```
export class Stomp {

public static brokerURL = null;
public static heartbeatIncoming: 0; // Typical value 0 - disabled
public static heartbeatOutgoing: 0; // Typical value 20000 - every 20 seconds
public static reconnectDelay: 5000;

constructor(private appConfig: AppConfig) {
  Stomp.brokerURL = this.appConfig.getConfig('openbatonWS') + '/websocketRD/websocket';
```

}

But had no luck. Can you point me into the right direction. How can I achieve to externalize brokerURL in InjectableRxStompConfig.

Thanks,
Urban

Answer (score 1):

I guess I was to tired to see the obvious, so I'll post an answer to my questions.
I had to put this into ngModule:

```
    {
      provide: InjectableRxStompConfig,
      useClass: Stomp,
      deps: [AppConfig]
    },
```

And use write class Stomp as this:

```
import {AppConfig} from "./app.config";

export class Stomp {

  public brokerURL = null;
  public heartbeatIncoming: 0; // Typical value 0 - disabled
  public heartbeatOutgoing: 0; // Typical value 20000 - every 20 seconds
  public reconnectDelay: 5000;

  constructor(private appConfig: AppConfig) {
    this.brokerURL = this.appConfig.getConfig('openbatonWS') + '/websocketRD/websocket';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @bam123!

I implemented it in the following way:

```
export class MyRxStompConfig extends InjectableRxStompConfig {
    constructor(private config: ConfigService) {
        super();
        this.brokerURL = this.config.brokerURL;
        this.heartbeatIncoming = 0;
        this.heartbeatOutgoing = 10000;
        this.reconnectDelay = 500;
    }
}
```

and I put the following in my app.module

```
{ provide: InjectableRxStompConfig, useClass: MyRxStompConfig, deps: [ConfigService] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wrapper service class for RxStompService and defined the methods to connect, destroy, send and receive message. So whenever calling this service. you can send the configuration details dynamically.

```
export class QueueMessageService implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  private rxStompConfig: InjectableRxStompConfig
  private rxStompService: RxStompService;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  fetchConfig(url :string): InjectableRxStompConfig {
    const myRxStompConfig: InjectableRxStompConfig = {
        // Which server?
        brokerURL: url,

        // Headers
        // Typical keys: login, passcode, host
        connectHeaders: {
          login: 'guest',
          passcode: 'guest'
        },

        // How often to heartbeat?
        // Interval in milliseconds, set to 0 to disable
        heartbeatIncoming: 0, // Typical value 0 - disabled
        heartbeatOutgoing: 0, // Typical value 20000 - every 20 seconds

        // Wait in milliseconds before attempting auto reconnect
        // Set to 0 to disable
        // Typical value 5000 (5 seconds)
        reconnectDelay: 200,

        // Will log diagnostics on console
        // It can be quite verbose, not recommended in production
        // Skip this key to stop logging to console
        debug: (msg: string): void => {
          console.log(new Date(), msg);
        }
      };
      return myRxStompConfig;
  }


  public connect(url: string) {
    this.rxStompConfig = this.fetchConfig(url);
    this.rxStompService = rxStompServiceFactory(this.rxStompConfig);
    this.rxStompService.activate;
  }

  public disconnect() {
    this.rxStompService.deactivate;
  }


  receiveMessage(topicName: string) {
    return this.rxStompService.watch(topicName);
  }

  sendMessage(topicName: string, message: string,createdBy: string) {
    var messageJson = {
        'Date': `${new Date}`,
        'Message':message,
        'CreatedBy':createdBy
     }
    return this.rxStompService.publish({destination: topicName, body: JSON.stringify(messageJson)});

  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.rxStompService.deactivate;
  }
}
```

And calling the service from the component like below. I have hard-coded the URL and topic names here but we can retrieve the values from config or from Rest-service etc.,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css']
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public receivedMessages: string[] = [];
  private topicSubscription: Subscription;


  constructor(private queueMessageService: QueueMessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.queueMessageService.connect(this.getQueueURL());
    this.topicSubscription = this.queueMessageService.receiveMessage(this.getTopicName()).subscribe((message: Message) => {
      this.receivedMessages.push(message.body);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.topicSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.queueMessageService.disconnect();
  }

   onSendMessage() {
     const message = `Paddy Message generated`;
     this.queueMessageService.sendMessage(this.getTopicName(),message,'user1');
  }

  getQueueURL(): string {
    return 'ws://127.0.0.1:61614//ws';
  }

  getTopicName(): string {
    return '/topic/demo';
  }
}
```